# Group item , filter them and count with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an sql query joining over FOUR tables returning filtered data.

These are my tables structures:

**ProductBase**

```
Id
ProductNumber
```

**ProductDocuments**

```
Id
Lang (like pl)
ProductBase_FK
```

**ProductCountry (N to M)**

```
Product_FK
Country_FK
```

**Country**

```
Id
CountryName (like Tschechien)
```

**QUERY**

```
Select MATNR, PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTBRAND, CountryName    , Lang FROM ProductBase prod 
inner join ProductDocuments doc ON prod.ID = doc.ProductBase_FK
inner join ProductCountryNM prodcountry ON prod.ID = prodcountry.Product_FK
inner join Countries country ON prodcountry.Country_FK = country.ID
where doc.DocType = 'xxx'
```

That's the result of the query:

```
MATNR   PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTBRAND    CoutryName  Lang
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          #Undefined
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          sk
3672367236  LowCell Wutera          AT          cs
3672367236  LowCell Wutera          AT          pl
```

As you can see I get all combinations from CoutryName AND Lang(uage) Field.

How can I get the COUNT of the Products (identifier is MATNR) where is at least minimum **ONE**  Lang(uage)  defined as '#Undefined'. That means "How many products still have incomplete countries"?

Note:

- If there exists only ONE Product with the same MATNR having '#Undefined' then it is to be seen as incomplete.
- If there exist ONE Product 4 times with the same MATNR having '#Undefined' then it is to be seen as incomplete.

SAMPLE

**Incomplete**

```
MATNR   PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTBRAND    CoutryName  Lang
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          #Undefined
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          at

MATNR   PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTBRAND    CoutryName  Lang
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          #Undefined
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          AT          #Undefined
```

**Complete**

```
MATNR   PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTBRAND    CoutryName  Lang
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          DE          de
5518543092  BigCell Wutera          FR          fr
```

WHEN there is **minimum** ONE '#Undefined' in the Lang for a Product then it's incomplete :-)

Comment: select count(MANTR) cnt, PRODUCTNAME where Lang = '#Undefined' group by PRODUCTNAME

Comment: Joining OVER four tables?!? So, five then?

Comment: No, see above there are 4 tables.

Comment: I don't understand your notes.  Can you give examples (in the question) of how they would apply?

Comment: I updated with some good samples :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about MS SQL Server 2012 but try this:

```
Select count(distinct MATNR) FROM ProductBase prod 
inner join ProductDocuments doc ON prod.ID = doc.ProductBase_FK
inner join ProductCountryNM prodcountry ON prod.ID = prodcountry.Product_FK
inner join Countries country ON prodcountry.Country_FK = country.ID
where doc.DocType = 'xxx' AND doc.LANG = '#Undefined'
```

Comment: Does not work. I get count 0 what can not be.  If you have 4 times the same MATNR where each row has Lang = '#Undefined' I need to get Count => 1 which means 1 incomplete product.

Comment: Yeah this should work.  the distinct on the count eliminates the multiple counts

Comment: Your query returns 5606 count. But @vkp returns 5943 count ??? Forget this comment! User vkp has a missing where constraint... I use in production...

Comment: Maybe because vkp doesn't limit on the doc.DocType='xxx'

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (Select MATNR, PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTBRAND, CountryName, Lang,
case when Lang = '#Undefined' then 1 else 0 end as cnt
FROM ProductBase prod
inner join ProductDocuments doc ON prod.ID = doc.ProductBase_FK
inner join ProductCountryNM prodcountry ON prod.ID = prodcountry.Product_FK
inner join Countries country ON prodcountry.Country_FK = country.ID)
select count(distinct matnr) 
from x where cnt = 1
```

Comment: Does not work. I get count 0 what can not be. If you have 4 times the same MATNR where each row has Lang = '#Undefined' I need to get Count => 1 which means 1 incomplete product. I updated my question with more info :-)